# how to see value of a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am setting a variable but I can't get the value back. How do I solve the issue?

```
PS C:\Users\manuchadha> Set-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE=https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com
PS C:\Users\manuchadha> Get-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'OPENAI_API_BASE'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OPENAI_API_BASE:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand
```

Comment: Just remove the `=`: `Set-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com`, see: `help -full set-variable`

Comment: `Set-Variable` and `Get-Variable` are rarely used in PowerShell. The idiomatic way to define a variable is to use the assignment operator `=` like so: `$OPENAI_API_BASE = 'https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com'`. To output a variable value, just write its name on its own line: `$OPENAI_API_BASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using the command would mean that

```
Set-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE=https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com
```

would create a variable called `"$OPENAI_API_BASE=https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com"` with no value. You can either use `Set-Variable -name OPENAI_API_BASE -value https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com`
or just use `$OPENAI_API_BASE=https://aoai-try-mc.openai.azure.com` at the PS prompt. To recall the contents use `Get-Variable OPENAI_API_BASE` or `$OPENAI_API_BASE` at the PS prompt.